# Excel 2010 How to make multiple scatter charts from same data

Tags: excel, charts

Have a data set from which I need to make several scatter plots (date vs. value). Each charts is different, based on different filters. To make one chart, I can filter my data, and then chart it. But if I change the filter, the chart changes. So I can't make any more charts, unless I make a copy of the data. Is there a way to make multiple charts from the same data set without making a copy of the data set for each chart? Pivot table/charts won't help me because I am making scatter plots. I don't want to summarize anything by date, for instance. I could have multiple events on the same date, and I don't want excel grouping them together.

Comment: If you don't need all your plots to be "live" then you can use `CopyPicture` to copy and paste each chart before you run the next filter. That will require VBA though.

Comment: If you use filters, you will probably need to create more than one data table. Depending on your data structure, though, and what exactly your filters do, you may be able to work with dynamic range names to feed charts instead of filtering the data. So, post a data sample and more detail about the specs so we can determine if dynamic ranges are an option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using multiple data regions?  See the following link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220577.aspx

I found it very helpful.

You can also write a code in VBA that will allow you to create multiple charts using different data points.  An example of this code can be found here:  http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=53320

Good luck!